# Ubuntu start in Emergency mode every time I turn on my PC

Tags: boot, grub2, live-usb, 21.10

[image]hello i have a problem, every time i start ubuntu it goes into emergency mode
I have already tried to do in `fsck.ext4 -y /dev/sdb3` and nothing keeps entering that mode that bothers me

Comment: Does `journalctl -xb` (as suggested) give any information on the state of the system?

Comment: in which line are the partitions

Comment: First line on the screenshot shows the file system is clean. You need to look at the journal for other errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try just hitting `CTRL-D`. If it comes back to the same screen, log in. You might need a password, but Ubuntu pretty much has training wheels on everything, so maybe you just hit `enter` to log in.

In most debian forks, such as Ubuntu, but maybe not Ubuntu, you enter the root password at the screen in your photograph, and you get `init level 1`, which is CLI ( command line line interface ), so you need to type in the commands. NO GUI!

But you should have networking. If you don't, that complicates things a bit, because you're going to need it. You'll need another PC to go online, unless you have networking, and then you would install `lynx` `apt install lynx`

You can launch any `cli` program (programs that run in a terminal) by typing the name. Every program should run from the shell you're in, if you were able to log in!

If you try `ping google.com` and nothing happens, you don't have networking. You really should ask a separate question for `how to activate networking from the command line`

I was always thrilled to have to punch my way back into the system using `cli` because then I could learn something new; something I couldn't just discipline myself to sit down and read about! You earn your stripes when you can't boot into the gui.

Have a look at the system log using the command `journalctl -xb` Look for anything like `warning` `failed`, stuff like that. You can page the /var/log/syslog file with `less /var/log/syslog` You can also filter for certain keywords, like `gdm`cat /var/log/syslog | grep gdm` Gdm is a good bet, because the gui won't come up without it.

You can usually repair the system by updating various packages, using dselect.

Comment: im going to try upgrading ubuntu from 21.10 to 22.04 tomorrow it will probably fix the problem